# Best strategy for querying data to display multiple graphs for a dashboard in html

Tags: jquery, database, elasticsearch

I'm building a very basic dashboard in HTML(jquery) with elastic search as backend. I'm displaying 8 different table/graph on the webpage. So when ever the page is reloaded or refreshed, the data is queried again. Is there a better strategy to query the data in an efficient way.

I'm thinking of storing the data in browser local storage for sometime and then refresh the data after some interval. But in that case immediate information may not be available.

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at how Kibana does it, every time the page is refreshed/reloaded the data is queried again. You can also set a timer that will reload the data on a defined interval. There's nothing wrong with it.

Elasticsearch is made to support near real-time searches, so caching data might still be useful if you have to deal with a slow RDBMS, but not for a properly tuned ES cluster.

Also caching is a performance optimization that should always come later in the game because as you probably know [premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization).